# Read all files in dir with targets and re-run when new added

Tags: r, target

Each month a new pdf file will be added to a specific dir. I am trying to build a data pipe line in `R` using `targets` to extract some information from these files.

```
list(
  tar_target(
    "data_path",
    list.files(path = "dir", full.names = T)
  )
  ,
  tar_target(
    "data_pdf_raw", 
    read_pdf(data_path),
    pattern = map(data_path)
  )
   ,
   tar_target(
     "data_pdf_clean", 
     clead_pdf(data_pdf_raw[[1]]),
     pattern = map(data_pdf_raw)
   )
   ,
   tar_target(
     "data_to_sql",
     data_to_sql(data_pdf_clean)
   )
)
```

The problem is that `targets` skip the `data_path` even thou new files are added in the dir. I have tried `format = "file"` in `data_path` without success. I have also tried to add a new target as mentioned in a post below.

```
tar_target(paths2, list_path, format = "file", pattern = map(data_path)),
```

As there are quite many pdfs and the process is time consuming I rather not re-read all files every single time.

I have noticed these two questions but the solutions does not work in my case.

[Using R Targets to Append New Data to Exisiting Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69036898/using-r-targets-to-append-new-data-to-exisiting-data)

[How should I use {targets} when I have multiple data files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69652540/how-should-i-use-targets-when-i-have-multiple-data-files)

Answer (score 0):

From the {targets} user manual (found here: https://books.ropensci.org/targets/dynamic.html) I figured out how to solve my issue with help from `tar_files()` in package `tarchetypes` and `format = "feather"`.

```
list(
  tar_files(
    "data_path",
    list.files(path = "dir", full.names = T)
  )
  ,
  tar_target(
    "data_pdf_raw", 
    read_pdf(data_path),
    pattern = map(data_path),
    format = "feather"
  )
)
```